# Normalizing date in MySQL where one column contains comma delimited items

Tags: mysql

I've got a database with one field that contains a comma delimited list that I'd like to normalize. The field would look something like this...

```
16-BIT, 20 MHz, MICROPROCESSOR, PQFP100
```

It will not always have the same number of commas delimited items, however the only item I care about, and the one I want to pull out and normalize is always going to be the last one, in the case above 'PQFP100'.

I think I understand the sql to get the column out and into another table, but I don't know how to select only the PQFP100 part of it. Here's what I have so far...

```
insert ignore into part_pkg (pkg_name)
select part_desc
from part_raw
group by pkg_name;
```

I think I need something on the 'from part_raw' part but don't even know where to start :)

Hopefully this is clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you select this:

```
select substring_index('16-BIT, 20 MHz, MICROPROCESSOR, PQFP100',',',-1)
```

you will get this:

```
PQFP100
```

So the insert statement must be something like this:

```
insert ignore into part_pkg (pkg_name)
select substring_index(part_desc',',',-1)
from part_raw
group by pkg_name;
```

Comment: Just tried it and that worked thanks a bunch! I did have to change 'substring_index' to upper case to get it to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert ignore into part_pkg (pkg_name)
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(part_desc, ',', -1)
from part_raw
group by pkg_name;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Gustavo... yours came in just behind the accepted answer but helped nonetheless